# How to call more than one java script function at a time in android to load the webview?

Tags: javascript, android, function, webview

i have a simple java script file.below is my sample js code

function autoplay(videoId, st, en) {
            player.loadVideoById({ 'videoId': videoId, 'startSeconds': st, 'endSeconds': en, 'suggestedQuality': 'small' });
            player.playVideo();
        }

```
    function getState(){
      alert(player.getPlayerState());
        return player.getPlayerState();
    }

    function CallTweak()
    {
      alert(player.getPlayerState());
      document.getElementById("mytext").innerHTML = player.getPlayerState();
      var data=player.getPlayerState();
       AndroidFunction.showToast(data);
      alert('second alert');
    }
```

i calling one function it works fine but i am trying to call two functions for example autoplay() and CallTweak() those methods are not called.
below is sample code for calling the functions

web_view.loadUrl("javascript:CallTweak()");
web_view.loadUrl("javascript:autoplay()");

How to call more than one function at a time in a single button click in android?Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey Rajesh, what are you trying to do exactly? Do you want to call both `CallTweak` and `autoplay` at the same time inside `web_view.loadUrl`?

Comment: yes,i want to call both functions same time

Comment: go ahead and take a look at my answer and see if it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take one of two approaches

Either, in your javascript code, define a third function which calls the other two

```
function callBothFunctions(){
    CallTweak();
    autoplay();
}
```

and then call that third function

```
web_view.loadUrl("javascript:callBothFunctions()");
```

**Or**, the other approach is to use an anonymous self-executing function like

```
 string javascriptFunctionCall = 
                      "javascript:"
                      + "(function(){"
                          + "CallTweak();"
                          + "autoplay();"
                      +"})()";

 web_view.loadUrl(javascriptFunctionCall);
```